# What will happen to the state of the tasklet when tasklet is running and hardware interrupt triggered?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

What will happen to the state of the tasklet when tasklet is executing and hardware interrupt triggered in the middle of tasklet execution ?

Answer (score 3):

Tasklet are the bottom half. They run in softirq context and not in hardware interrupt context. So hardware interrupts are always enabled. When hardware interrupts is triggered while executing tasklets then it will interrupt the tasklet. Then top half is run on the respective IRQ stack and acknowledge the interrupt. This behavior is especially useful with interrupt handlers, where the hardware interrupt must be managed as quickly as possible, but most of the data management can be safely delayed to a later time. Actually, a tasklet, just like a kernel timer, is executed (in atomic mode) in the context of a soft interrupt, a kernel mechanism that executes asynchronous tasks with hardware interrupts enabled.

Comment: Right !! If suppose hard interrupts are enabled and tasklet is preempted and isr quickly finish its job. Then, at what time , tasklet will be executed because it may be possible that i am keep on getting hard interrupt and tasklet may not execute till *significant* time or may not get chance to run.  If you say "like a kernel timer" that means you are talking about clock if so then is tasklet schedule before next tick and if it doesn't run till next tick what will be happen with the tasklet ? Could you please elaborate your POV ?

Comment: There are rules for tasklet scheduling:
       `1.In the return from hardware interrupt code path 

        2.In the ksoftirqd kernel thread 

        3.In any code that explicitly checks for and executes pending softirqs, such as the networking subsystem`

If too many hardware interrupts are fired yes there is a possibility that tasklet won't get schedule. In fact such situation might results in "soft lockup"

Comment: @ skaushal : I don't think , it always run in soft interrupt context. May be i wrong ?  ksofirqd will be called in process context under heavy load. Soft interrupts are normally serviced on  return from a hard interrupt (do_irq), but it is possible for soft interrupts to be invoked more quickly than they can be serviced. If a soft interrupt is triggered for a 2nd time while soft interrupts are being handled, the ksoftirq daemon is triggered to handle the soft interrupts in process context. So in case of too may interrupt, i would ksofirqd mechanism. Please put some light on this !!

Comment: @Manish: Tasklet in general runs in softirq context. Your original question was generic so my answer was generic. Your above comment is digression from your original question. I would like to clarify your doubts but not able to get your point. Do you have any specific scenario involving hard interrupts and tasklets? I would like to answer that. As there could be many cases in which tasklet may take different variants of spinlock depending on the situation.

Comment: **@skaushal** : No, I don't have specific scenario.  However, if you see my original ques is stating that "what will happen in case of running tasklet handler if hard irq trigger ?" so your answer was "it will interrupt the tasklet" that is what exactly should be happened. 1) But when will my tasklet be run if i am keep on getting hard irq. 2) Though, tasklet is interrupted bcoz of hard irq, but it'll have to finish minimum things before being interrupted. Exactly , what point will it be interrupted? 3) In case of "soft lockup", how does kernel deal with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check `tasklet_schedule` function.

It will save the state of the interrupt system and restore interrupts to their previous state and return after `do_softirq` operation.

Answer (score -1):

Tasklets run in interrupt context. So code in tasklets should not  sleep (or be interrupted). If the tasklet is interruped by an interrupt, your system crashes.  To prevent interrupts while running tasklet you have to prevent the interrupts by using `spinlock_irq_save()`

Comment: The `spin_lock_irqsave()` is not always  the right choice. It depends on what data you are protecting and in what context. More often tasklets protects data via `spin_lock_bh()`.

Comment: @Milind : if it runs in interrupt context. Then, it can't be preempt by other interrupt. It has to have complete its jobs before catering anything else. If so then it might be possible that my interrupt get lost.  Could you please correct me ?

Comment: @Andy: As milind told us about usage of spin_lock_irqsave but you have pointed towards spin_lock_bh. This api disable the software interrupt before taking a lock but still hard irq will remain enabled. I am working on 2.4.29 where when we schedule tasklet using tasklet_schedule(), it does local_irq_save and then restore so if i use spin_lock_irqsave , it will again do save and restore irq which tasklet_schedule is doing inside it code. I rather opt spin_lock alone.  However, Andy has mentioned spin_lock_bh(), i've not used this. Andy , Could you please put some light on it?

Comment: @Andy : Two tasklet of same type can't run concurrently so what is usage of lock ? I can see lock in case of different tasklet share common data but could you ( Andy and Milind) share an example where data is shared bw two different tasklet ?  Secondly, we may use simple spin_lock instead of spin_loc_bh()  because tasklet can't preept another running tasklet on same cpu.  Please inputs your vital comments.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko: Ohh..in case of tasklet scheduling, we disable or enable local irq. so my line --- "when we schedule tasklet using tasklet_schedule(), it does local_irq_save and then restore so if i use spin_lock_irqsave , it will again do save and restore irq which tasklet_schedule is doing inside it code" ---- is incorrect. I may pick spin_lock_irqsave to avoid an interruption in running tasklet. I don't much about what "Andy" has pointed out. Thanx guys to steal some time out of your busy schedule and answer this question !!